# Nexus 4 not loading/not showing in ADB devices

Tags: android, windows-7, nexus-4

I recently accidentally "updated" the OS to 4.4 while using a 4.3 rooted OS, which turned it into a very expensive paper weight. I can load into the recovery state (Power+down vol), but i cant load past the Google boot screen. I believe the entire phone has been completely wiped.

I'm running windows 7 and have the adb interface correctly installed. I've followed every step to the letter. win7 sees the phone in device manager.

When I do a "adb devices" command, nothing shows up. I can't set the USB debugging, because i believe the OS has been wiped clean.

FASTBOOT MODE
mako
mako 16gb
rev_11
MAKOZ20i
M9615A-CEFWMAZM-2.0.1700.84
None
serial number
production
enabled
unlocked

I have what i need to do the adb sideload, but i need help in what i can do to get it to work?

Comment: Don't use adb sideload. Use fastboot to flash a factory image.

Comment: Do you have a link to where where i can follow steps?

Comment: never mind, i think i found one! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Here is what i have found that i hope works for me. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2010312

Comment: This one worked for me a few days ago. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that i found for using fastboot. I'm currently at the animated logo, hoping that it is building the Dalvik cache. This has gotten me farther than before!

Thanks [Raghav Sood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) for the tip!

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2010312